# Gap and Island problem - query not working for all periods

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands

I have to create a query to find the gaps and islands between dates. This seems to be a standard gaps and island problem. To show my issue I will use sample of data. The queries are executed in Snowflake.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (StartDate date, EndDate date);
INSERT INTO TEST
SELECT '8/20/2017', '8/21/2017'  UNION ALL
SELECT '8/22/2017', '9/22/2017'  UNION ALL
SELECT '8/23/2017', '9/23/2017'  UNION ALL 
SELECT '8/24/2017', '8/26/2017'  UNION ALL 
SELECT '8/28/2017', '9/19/2017'  UNION ALL 
SELECT '9/23/2017', '9/27/2017'  UNION ALL 
SELECT '9/25/2017', '10/10/2017' UNION ALL
SELECT '10/17/2017','10/18/2017' UNION ALL 
SELECT '10/25/2017','11/3/2017'  UNION ALL 
SELECT '11/3/2017', '11/15/2017';
```

This code gives me a sample of table.

Then I have the code to find gaps and islands:

```
SELECT
    MIN(StartDate) AS IslandStartDate,
    MAX(EndDate) AS IslandEndDate
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE WHEN PreviousEndDate >= StartDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IslandStartInd,
        SUM(CASE WHEN PreviousEndDate >= StartDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY Groups.RN) AS IslandId
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY StartDate,EndDate) AS RN,
            StartDate,
            EndDate,
            LAG(EndDate,1) OVER (ORDER BY StartDate, EndDate) AS PreviousEndDate
        FROM
            TEST
    ) Groups
) Islands
GROUP BY
    IslandId
ORDER BY 
    IslandStartDate
```

The results are:

[image]

As you see the problem is for period 8/28/2017 - 9/19/2017.
This period should not be a separate island, because it should be included in the period: 8/23/2017 - 9/23/2017.

Do you have any idea how I can modify my query to get the correct results (so instead 6 I should have 5 islands as 8/28/2017 - 9/19/2017 should not be island). This just example of data, so I am looking for unversal solution, but so far I have not figure out the correct approach.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express the gaps-and-islands logic like this:

```
select min(startdate), max(enddate)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_enddate >= startdate then 0 else 1 end) over (order by startdate) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   max(enddate) over (order by startdate rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_enddate
            from test t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp
order by min(startdate);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1577dd6cdabdc3037528e430b4b2a90a) is a db<>fiddle.

The idea is to look for the maximum enddate on all the "earlier" rows.  This value is used to check if there is an overlap.

So, the innermost subquery calculates the previous enddate.  The middle subquery does a cumulative sum of the beginnings of groups to assign a group identifier.

The outer query just aggregates by the group identifier.

Comment: Thank you, I am validating the data, but all looks good so far, your solution works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the overlapping records from the original set:

```
SELECT MinStart as StartDate, MaxEnd as EndDate
FROM Test data
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(StartDate) MinStart, MAX(EndDate) MaxEnd FROM TEST lkp WHERE lkp.StartDate < data.EndDate AND lkp.EndDate > data.StartDate) bounds
GROUP BY MinStart, MaxEnd
```

| StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-08-20 | 2017-08-21 |
| 2017-08-22 | 2017-09-23 |
| 2017-08-23 | 2017-10-10 |
| 2017-10-17 | 2017-10-18 |
| 2017-10-25 | 2017-11-03 |
| 2017-11-03 | 2017-11-15 |

> In this current result set, no additional duplications have occurred, but in a larger recordset there would be more potential for a much larger range of contiguous records. Meaning you may need to recursively execute this lookup.

Putting that together you get:

```
SELECT
    MIN(StartDate) AS IslandStartDate,
    MAX(EndDate) AS IslandEndDate
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE WHEN PreviousEndDate >= StartDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IslandStartInd,
        SUM(CASE WHEN PreviousEndDate >= StartDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY Groups.RN) AS IslandId
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY StartDate,EndDate) AS RN,
            StartDate,
            EndDate,
            LAG(EndDate,1) OVER (ORDER BY StartDate, EndDate) AS PreviousEndDate
        FROM
        (
            SELECT MinStart as StartDate, MaxEnd as EndDate
            FROM Test data
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(StartDate) MinStart, MAX(EndDate) MaxEnd FROM TEST lkp WHERE lkp.StartDate < data.EndDate AND lkp.EndDate > data.StartDate) bounds
            GROUP BY MinStart, MaxEnd       
        ) Normalized
    ) Groups
) Islands
GROUP BY
    IslandId
ORDER BY 
    IslandStartDate
```

This results in **4** islands, not 5 as you were originally expecting, because of your 2nd and 3rd input lines *AND the 6th and 7th lines*, they create an Island that spans 8/22 - 10/10 !

```
SELECT '8/22/2017', '9/22/2017' UNION ALL
SELECT '8/23/2017', '9/23/2017' UNION ALL 
...
SELECT '9/23/2017', '9/27/2017'  UNION ALL 
SELECT '9/25/2017', '10/10/2017' UNION ALL
```

| IslandStartDate | IslandEndDate |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-08-20 | 2017-08-21 |
| 2017-08-22 | 2017-10-10 |
| 2017-10-17 | 2017-10-18 |
| 2017-10-25 | 2017-11-15 |